# How to completely disable mouse grab in qemu

Tags: mouse, virtualization, gui, qemu

I want to test bootable iso files with qemu. I feel very discomfort that when I click inside qemu window, the mouse gets grabbed and you need to press Ctrl + Alt + G to release it.

In VirtualBox there is a per vm setting, which allows me to do that:
`VBoxManage setextradata "VM name" GUI/MouseCapturePolicy Disabled`

Is it possible to do the same with qemu? I did not found such a parameter in manual (or maybe I am missing something). May it be dependent on vga type?

Comment: The only thing about mouse I see is spice agent-mouse=[on|off].

Comment: Probably it is possible with kde window scripts? The script should detect when window is in focus, then if mouse click happens, catch it. Then check if it was above qemu window. If it was the case, drop it. Otherwise pass it. And this script should be launched simultaneously with qemu machine.

Comment: For now, as a workaround, I am using VirtualBox. I use these commands to automate: `VBoxManage controlvm iso-testing poweroff
sleep 2
VBoxManage startvm iso-testing`
also, it directly boots to uefi shell, which I could not achieve yet with qemu.